# python for loop expression of iterator

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a for loop in which I use the iterator always in the same manner, like this

```
for dict in mylist:
    var = dict['prop']
    var2 = f( dict['prop'] )
    ...
```

This is clumsy. The only alternatives I can think of:

- local variable
- wrapping the mylist in a list comprehension. But that seems overkill and is probably inefficient

Any better way?

Comment: I don't see any problems with that, although I'd write it as `var, var2 = dict['prop'], f(dict['prop'])`

Comment: To be honest, I am not seeing the clumsiness (except the unnecessary second lookup of `dict['prop']`). Perhaps show us more of your code?

Comment: for dict_prop=dict['prop'] in mylist: ...  would seem more natural for me. Just looking if I missed some python feature

Comment: I'd go with a local variable in the loop. And I wouldn't use `dict` as a variable name...

Comment: I think you might actually be looking for something like the [`With` statement in Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu58.html#x155-16500013.2.8) (Python does have a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), but it does something different). So you might be interested in this article: [Why doesn't Python have a "with" statement like some other languages?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesn-t-python-have-a-with-statement-like-some-other-languages.htm).

Answer (score 0):

One map call would work to give you a list of tuples of values:

```
listOfTuples = map(lambda x: (dict['prop'], f(dict['prop']), myList)
```

Or if you want two separate lists of values:

```
[varList, var2List] = zip(*zip(listOfTuples))
```